# TablLayout em um fragment ocupando espaço todo

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde. Quero fazer um app onde eu tenha um menu lateral, com opções padroes, do tipo "página inicial, perfil, sobre etc...". Quando eu clicar em página inicial, quero que a minha tela vire uma tablayout, com duas abas. Para isto, fiz na minha tela principal o menu lateral, e um relative layout, onde vou colocar meus fragments para ocupar a tela. porém, quando boto meu fragment contendo as Abas, ela ocupa a tela toda, não aparecendo as pages que adiciono nela. No incio, para teste, fiz apenas as tabs, direto no layout principal, sem fragments, e estava tudo ok. queria saber como fazer ficar certo... Já tentei trocar quase tudo que dava dos widths e heigths, mas nada funcionou.

**.java do fragmento das abas**

```
public FragAbas() {

}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_abas, container, false);

    ViewPager viewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());


    adapter.addFragment(new FragOferta(), "Ofertas");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragProcura(), "Procuras");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

**xml do frag das abas**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_below="@id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabTextColor="#000000"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**.java do menu**

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicial);

    setMenu();
    setFragOnMenu();
}

private void setMenu() {
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

private void setFragOnMenu(){
    NavigationView nv = findViewById(R.id.menuLateral);
    nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            Fragment fr = null;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_pag_inicial:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "aaah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fr = new FragAbas();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_como_funciona:
                    fr = null;
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_perfil:
                    fr = null;
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_dados_pessoais:
                    fr = null;
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_negociacoes:
                    fr = null;
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_sobre:
                    fr = null;
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_sair:
                    fr = null;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            if (fr != null){
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relativeContainer, fr).commit();
            }
            item.setChecked(true);

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**xml do menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeContainer">

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navegation_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/menuLateral">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

[image: Como está ficando][image: Como era]